# What's the full sentence of "No point both of us getting wet"?

Tags: grammar, phrases, syntactic-analysis, conversational-deletion

I came across the phrase "No point both of us getting wet" from 'Me before you' novel. Is this phrase from the full sentence of "There is no point (in) both of us getting wet"?
If so, anyone could give me suggestion if there is some ways in English grammar rules to minimize this sentence into just a phrase, please?

Comment: Your hunch is correct. I believe that our resident linguistics prof, John Lawler, has some answers about the "conversational deletion rules" you're looking for, possibly referencing published stuff of his. Basically, you are allowed to delete whatever front parts of a sentence in conversation which are "obvious" to both parties.

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/a/58445 http://english.stackexchange.com/a/66994 http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/262312/obvious-subject-in-a-sentence/262597#comment576241_262312

Comment: Why should we both get wet?

Comment: Another question, "Getting wet" is a present participle modifying "us"? So actually the unshortened sentence should be "There is no point (in) both of us who get wet"?  Thanks :)